# How can i fix code that calculates power of two integers in assembly code

Tags: assembly, arm

i have a task to write int power (int n, int m) in arm_32 and use it in C program, the function should return n^m

I made the code like this, but for some reason it does not work

```
@ Int power (int n, int m)
@ r0               r1      r2

.text
.align 2
.global power
power:
stmfd sp!, {fp, lr}
mov fp, sp

mov r3, #0 @ loop counter is 0
mov r4, r1 @ i moved n to register r 4

loop:
cmp r2,r3  @ if m==loop counter
beq end    @ jump to end
mul r4, r1, r4  @ multiply
add r3,r3,#1  @ add 1 on counter
b loop @ jump to begining of loop

mov r0,r4 @ put the result in r0

end:
Mov sp, fp
Ldmfd sp!, {fp,pc}
```

In my C program it prints:

```
4 2    5 2
2      2
```

Which is incorrect, any help about this would be greatly apriciated :D

Comment: Hint: how do you expect the `put the result in r0` line to be executed?

Comment: What was your input?  What you have here is going to compute a value one power too high  (So 2,5 will produce 64 instead of 32).  You might consider `mov r4, #1` in that first statement so that a power of 0 produces a value of 1.

Comment: You also need to save r4 or you clobber some register that the 'C' code is using.

Comment: @Jester well in the end i have mov r0, r4 i think that should move the r4 to r0, which is the result register, if my thinking is wrong how should i then type it?

Comment: @TimRoberts when i put 4 2 or 5 2 it always prints out 2, like 3 3 it would print 3, it seems to me like it doesnt even go into the loop, the mistake that you have pointed out i can understand, but the problem is the loop since it doesnt print numbers even close to the solution

Comment: What Jester is correctly trying to point out is that the `mov r0, r4` instruction will never be executed.  When the loop is over, you jump to `end`, and that's AFTER the `mov`.  Another way to solve this is just to use `r0` as your accumulator instead of `r4`.

Comment: @TimRoberts soo if i put that line in the end section, that should fix the problem?

Comment: It would have been quicker to try it than to wait for an answer here.

Comment: @TimRoberts yea that is true, i will try it a bit later and post here if the problem is fixed, and thanks for help :)

Comment: As I see it, `i` is in `r0` and `j` is in `r1` upon function entry, but you're multiplying `r1` × `r2`, no?

Comment: Don't just run it to see what happens in the end, use the debugger to single step and verify every line of code is ok.  If one line is bad or missing, your whole program won't work — running it without the debugger to see the end results isn't really an approach to debugging.

Comment: @ErikEidt in r0 should be the result, in r1 is n(the number that we will power) and in r2 is m(the power) and mul r4,r1,r4 means multiply r1*r4 and put the product in r4

Comment: @ErikEidt yea i guess you have a point about debugging im installing linux now to try and fix it since they force me on my university to use linux only, and i had this question on exam today

Comment: @MarkoPetrovic, I don't know any real ARM calling convention that passes 1st parameter in `r1` instead of `r0` — just doesn't exist as far as I know.  Are you sure you have correct information?  Is this very hypothetical?  FYI, there's nothing wrong with parameter in `r0` and return value also in `r0` since parameters are on function entry and return value much later (at exit) — the underlying machine code simply has to be written to accommodate that.

Comment: @ErikEidt sorry my mistake, you are right the n is in r0 and m is in r1, i dont know why i thought it started with r1, i think that this may solve the problem completely i will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected ARM assembly code that you can use

```
@ Int power (int n, int m)
@ r0               r1      r2

.text
.align 2
.global power
power:
    stmfd sp!, {r4, fp, lr}
    mov fp, sp

    mov r3, #1  @ loop counter is 1
    mov r4, r1  @ i moved n to register r4

loop:
    cmp r2, r3  @ if m == loop counter
    beq end     @ jump to end
    mul r4, r4, r1  @ multiply
    add r3, r3, #1  @ add 1 to the counter
    b loop     @ jump to beginning of loop

end:
    mov r0, r4  @ put the result in r0

    mov sp, fp
    ldmfd sp!, {r4, fp, pc}
```

Make sure to assemble and link this corrected code and then use it in your C program. It should produce the correct result for calculating n^m

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you have `mov r0,r4` positioned physically after the loop but it is not positioned in the logically executing instruction stream, because the instruction stream simply skips around that instruction.  Any instructions that appear physically between an unconditional branch (e.g. `b loop`) and a label (e.g. `end:`) is almost certainly what we call dead or unreachable code, and so serves no purpose!

Move that instruction from immediately before to instead immediately after the `end:` label.

---

On another matter, that code is multiplying `r1` × `r2`, when the parameters are actually passed in `r0` and `r1`, for `n` and `m`, respectively.

---

While some ABIs/calling conventions use different registers for return value than any arguments, it is not uncommon for a calling convention to use the same register for function return value as for first argument.  MIPS & x64 do not, while RISC V & ARM do.  There are situations that make either approach better than the other; the former style offers a clarity that the return register is immediately available for use in the function, whereas the latter style allows more registers for parameter passing.

While `r0` in this case has two usages for the function, one is at function entry and the other at function exit, these differing usages don't technically conflict at those ends points — just that you may have to juggle some values upon return, as you're already doing using `r4` as the accumulator and copying to `r0` later.

---

Also, do not use `r4`-`r9` unless you save & restore them as this would be a violation of the calling convention.  I think you should be able to make it work using just the 4 scratch/parameter registers.  Recall that the parameter registers, while they hold values, you're allowed to modify them and the caller cannot complain about that.  (So, one approach is decrementing to zero instead of incrementing to match, if you're low on scratch registers; however in ARM32, there are several other scratch registers, namely r12, for example; consult your reference materials if needed.)

---

As an aside, your function should work ok without a stack frame, so only really create one if your assignment/problem requires it.